# Google Site Links showing the H3 class in front

Tags: html, hyperlink

Google has generated site links from my page to display when you search, but it shows 'H3' in front of the text on the site link, i'll show a screen shot below

[Picture of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfV35.png)

If someone could help me out on ways to fix this, then that would be great!

Thanks :)

Comment: What is your site? My guess is that you added h3 in your header, but without the actual URL and code, it's hard to help further.

Comment: Hello Victoria, thanks for the response. Here is the link to the website that i am having the issue with, thanks. http://www.copyreddone.com/our-services/